# Comma separated search in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have search mechanism in my site. For that I have written a large conditional query.

```
$sql = "select * from users where 
keyword like '%".$_POST['search']."%' 
OR name like '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
```

Now, I suppose I have following data on the site:

```
ID    Name    Keyword
1     Sanjay  sanjay, surani
2     Ankit   ankit, shah
3     Ravi    ravi, kotwani
```

Now, I need the result such that when user writes `"sanjay, shah" ($_POST['search'] = 'sanjay, shah')` then records 1 and 2 should be displayed.

Can I achieve this in single mysql query?

Comment: As an aside, using un-checked user input (GET or POST data, for example) directly in your queries is a *very bad* idea and opens you up to SQL injection. At the very least, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to sanitise user input.

Answer (score 2):

What if you were to restructure the keyword field and break it up so that it had only a single name in it?

So instead of

```
ID    Name    Keyword
1     Sanjay  sanjay, surani
2     Ankit   ankit, shah
3     Ravi    ravi, kotwani
```

you'd have

```
ID    Name    KeyID
1     Sanjay  1
2     Sanjay  2
3     Ankit   3
4     Ankit   4
5     Ravi    5
6     Ravi    6

KeyID Keyword
1     sanjay
2     surani
3     ankit
4     shah
5     ravi
6     kotwani
```

Searches would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

here it is :

```
$query_elems = explode(",", $query);
$searches = array();
foreach($query_elems as $qe){
    $searches[] = "keyword like '%" . trim($qe) . "%' or name like '%" . trim($qe) . "%'";
}
$query = "select * from users where " . implode(" or ",$searches);
$result = mysql_query($query)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right I can achieve in this way. But I have just put the example here. My actualy query is 200 lines long in my php file. So if I will do in above way, I will have to do so many changes and might cause re-testing of whole the functionality etc.

So I want some way (regex or full text search etc.) which can handle my problem in query only in place of OR....

Comment: you can create a temptable with names and then left join the users?

Answer (score 0):

Use php in_array this will simplify your problem